# Use Printer on network From a React Native mobile application

Tags: react-native, thermal-printer, escpos, network-printers, expo-go

I am trying to create an android application using expo react native which can access a printer (connected to the same network) to print a simple receipt. I am fine with any type of implementation as long as it doesnt have too many issues. Would appreciate the help if you could point me in the right direction (a package which works) or provide me with a small project which I can use to develop my app (preferabely). In dire need of assistance.

(Printer is Black Copper BC-105 80mm Thermal Receipt Printer)

I tried several packages like:
https://github.com/AllInOneYT/react-native-thermal-printer
and
https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer
But I wasnt able to make any of them work.
Here is the link to the src files of an app I made to test multiple packages and methods:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16jkhzeWTXzRbhcdUq15Xm1OKTtTbzEsD?usp=sharing